# Call component method when service's signal updates

Tags: angular, typescript, signals, angular16

Let me preface this question with the fact that I started learning Angular about a month ago.

Basically, I have a searchbar component and several different itemcontainer components (each of them displays a different type of item). In an attempt to have access to the serchbar value on any component, I created a searchbarService like so:

```js
import { Injectable, signal, WritableSignal } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchBarService {

  searchTextSignal: WritableSignal<string> = signal('');

  setSearch(text: string): void{
    this.searchTextSignal.set(text);
  }
}
```

The searchbar component calls the setSearch method on input submit. So far so good. Now, the problem comes when trying to work with searchTextSignal on the itemcontainter components. I'm trying to use it like this:

```js
import { Component, signal} from '@angular/core';
import { Factura } from 'src/app/interfaces/factura';
import { FacturaService } from 'src/app/services/factura.service'; //gets items from a placeholder array.
import { SearchBarService } from 'src/app/services/search-bar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'vista-facturas',
  templateUrl: './vista-facturas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vista-facturas.component.css']
})
export class VistaFacturasComponent {

    facturasArray: Factura[] = []; // has all items
    filteredFacturasArray = signal<Factura[]>([]); // has all filtered items, and is the value that I want to get updated when the signal changes.

    constructor(private facturaService: FacturaService, public searchBarService: SearchBarService) { }

    getFacturas(): void { //initializes the arrays.
        this.facturaService.getFacturas().subscribe(facturasReturned => this.facturasArray = facturasReturned);
        this.filteredFacturasArray.set(this.facturasArray);
    }

    filterFacturas(): void{ // this method is likely the problem

        let text = this.searchBarService.searchTextSignal();

        if (!text) 
            this.filteredFacturasArray.set(this.facturasArray);
        
        this.filteredFacturasArray.set(this.facturasArray.filter(factura => factura?.numero.toString().includes(text)));
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getFacturas();
    }
}
```

The templace uses ngFor like so:

```html
<div class="item-container">
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let factura of filteredFacturasArray()"> 
         <!-- template for the items -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So, everything boils down to how to make VistaFacturasComponent call filterFacturas() when searchBarService.searchTextSignal() updates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Storytellerr's idea and subsequent error message, I had this idea and it ended up working (it might look ugly and unreadable but it works):

```js
filterText: Signal<string> = computed( () => this.searchBarService.searchTextSignal().replace(/^\D+/g, ''));

filteredFacturasArray: Signal<Factura[]> = computed(() => this.facturasArray.filter(factura => factura?.numero.toString().includes(this.filterText())));
```

basically defining a filterText computed that depends on searchBarService.searchTextSignal(), and then defining filteredFacturasArray as another computed that depends on filterText. Because both of these values directly depend on searchBarService.searchTextSignal(), whenever it changes they update automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can hook the signal change by using [effects](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects), An **effect** is an operation that runs whenever one or more signal values change.
you can use effects in your constructor for any change in signals.

```
constructor(
    private facturaService: FacturaService,
    public searchBarService: SearchBarService
  ) {
    effect(() => {
      this.filterFacturas();
    });
  }
```

Here is a [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rmymql?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch-result%2Fsearch-result.component.ts).

Comment: I'm getting this error from it "Error: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an `effect` by default. Use `allowSignalWrites` in the `CreateEffectOptions` to enable this inside effects.", but the error code gave a good idea that might work, so thank you still :p

Comment: effects are web hooks(trigger functions)  which will be called every time any signal is updated. you cannot edit any other signal inside effect as this will start an endless loop.